# Re-entry to Canada

Tags: air-travel, residency

I have a Canadian PR card valid until September 2018. I traveled to Canada first in September 2013 and came back along with my family during May 2014. I was in my home country and never traveled back to Canada again. Can I travel again to Canada with the PR card, which is valid until September 2018?

What is the procedure for re-entry in my scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From [the government of Canada's website](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/new-immigrants/pr-card/understand-pr-status.html)

> **Time spent living in Canada**
>
> When you are a permanent resident, you can
>   live outside of Canada, but must live in Canada for at least two years
>   in a five-year period. If you live outside of Canada for longer, you
>   may lose your permanent resident status.
>
> For more information on how long you have to live in Canada, see
>   [Appendix A: Residency obligation](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/application-forms-guides/guide-5445-applying-permanent-resident-card-card-first-application-replacement-renewal-change-sex-designation.html#appendixA) of the PR card application package.

From Appendix A: Residency obligation:

> **Minimum residency obligation**
>
> **You must meet the residency obligation to get a PR Card.**
>
> If you have been a permanent resident for five (5) years or more
>
> - you must have been physically present in Canada for a minimum of 730    days within the past five (5) years.
>
> **If you have been a permanent resident for less than five (5) years**
>
> - you must show that you will be able to meet the minimum of 730 days    of physical presence in Canada within five (5) years of the date you
>     became a permanent resident.

It looks like you have spent too much time living outside Canada and could get your permanent residency removed. I'd contact your local Canadian Embassy or Consulate.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the validity of your PR card has nothing to do with the PR status and the PR residency obligation (RO) that you have to meet which states that you have to live in Canada for a total of 2 years within a five year period to maintain PR. Your PR card will expire every 5 years irrespective of whether you have lived in Canada forever as PR.

You should basically look up the calendar and count the number of days (years) you have physically lived in Canada. If you have lived there less than 2 years between Sep 2013-2018 (assuming you became a PR in Sept 2013) then you have failed to meet the RO and will lose your PR status the next time you try to enter or apply for immigration papers when they check your RO status.

Based on your description, even if you fly out today to Canada you will possibly not meet the 2-year RO till Sep 2018.